# How to make PInvoke SafeHandle for VirtualAlloc

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I'm trying to figure out a way to have my pinvoke signature for VirtualAlloc return a PageAlignedBuffer.  The problem I'm having is that I can't have a default constructor because the VirtualFree method needs to know the buffer size so I have to provide it in the constructor.  For this reason I've taken the approach below and Just call VirtualAlloc from within the constructor.

Does anyone see a way around this so I can just return a PageAlignedBuffer from the pinvoke call?  If not is this an okay solution, do you see it having any issues around security or memory leaks?  Thanks.

```
[SecurityCritical]
public sealed class PageAlignedBuffer : SafeBuffer
{
    private readonly UIntPtr _bufferSize = UIntPtr.Zero;
    public PageAlignedBuffer(long bufferSize) : base(true)
    {
        _bufferSize = checked ((UIntPtr) bufferSize);
        this.handle = WinAPI.VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, _bufferSize, AllocationType.RESERVE | AllocationType.COMMIT, MemoryProtection.READWRITE);
    }
    [SecurityCritical]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return WinAPI.VirtualFree(this.handle, _bufferSize, FreeType.Release);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass zero for `dwSize` when you call `VirtualFree` in `ReleaseHandle`, [as mentioned on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the dwFreeType parameter is MEM_RELEASE, this parameter must be 0
>   (zero). The function frees the entire region that is reserved in the
>   initial allocation call to VirtualAlloc.

Thus, you don't need to store `_bufferSize`, but you'd still need to derive a class from `SafeBuffer`, because `SafeBuffer` is an abstract class which requires you to implement`ReleaseHandle` in your derived class, to deal with specific resource type. This way, your `PageAlignedBuffer` is a managed class and you just cannot make `VirtualAlloc` API return an instance of it or cast an unmanaged pointer to it. So, the rest of your code looks good to me.